# Knockout Custom Validation not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I cannot figure out what I am missing here.  Any ideas as to why the binding is not taking please let me know.

Here is my validation:

```
ko.validation.rules["MinArrayLength"] = {
    validator : (array, params) => {
        return array.length >= params.minLength;
    },
    message: "Array does not meet minimum length requirements."
};
```

Here is where I add it to my array:

```
this.addresses = ko.observableArray<AddressModel>()
    .extend({
        MinArrayLength: { minLength: 1, message : 'At least 1 Address is Required.' }
    });
```

I had some issues in the past with people arguing that I was not initializing my code.  Below is from my Chrome Console.  The rule is added to the global validation rules set but its not added to the observable array's rule set.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be working now that I have added: ko.validation.registerExtenders();

What I would really like to know is why I need this now but have not needed it in the past.

Comment: which version of Knockout-Validation are you using? The latest on GitHub https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/blob/master/src/configuration.js (version 2.0.3) shows that the default value for registerExtenders is true. Do you have an init function somewhere that is/was setting that to false before?

Comment: I am using 2.0.3, I am doing this in TypeScript:
I have each validation in a private function.  Those functions are in a module which as a single public function that calls each of the private functions.  That public one is called from a master file which is called on page load.  I have not had to use the registerExtenders() in the past to have my validations work.  As I said, I added it and now the validation is working but its just odd why other validations worked without having it called.